# FPC/Lazarus component like TImageList, but for generic files?

Tags: resources, components, lazarus, freepascal

Just like TImageList contains a collection of images, is there a similar component for generic files?

I know I can embed files as resources, but I'd like the convenience of storing different groups of files in different "TFileList" components, and to be able to retrieve files by name or by their position in the list.

Extra points if such a component allowed some sort of design time preview of the file content (just like TImageList lets you see what each image looks like, at design time).

(I come from Delphi where I wrote my own component to do the above, but before I rewrite and port the property editor and all that to Lazarus, maybe there is already something that is tried and tested...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use pre-defined lazarus TFPGList to specialize list of the type, that you want, for example - UTF8String
But, there's no T<>List as a component, only as object.
So, yes, this feature will be useful and i can implement, if have time,
also, there's a very limited RTTI, which has been updated only a few months ago, so you can access Methods and Properties now, so FP is more systemized, than delphi pascal, but also not so enterprise-developed, which limits it to implementations for common opensource and shareware project problems.
Nevertheless, it is more stable and supported, even my friends can contribute.

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with "list of type" as objects. However what I need here is 1) a design-time component, and 2) allow multiple file types, not just one type.  You can think of that as an alternative to using embedded resources.